# Why does this recursion in C print backwards?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, recursion

I would think the output of this program would be 4321. i.e. modulo 1234 = 4, then divide by 10 gives you 123, so modulo 123 = 3...which when finished should be 4321. But the output is 1234. Can someone please explain how this is happening? Many thanks and happy holidays.

```
void printnumber(int n) { //function declaration
    if (n < 0) {
        putchar('-');
        printnumber(-n); //recursive call
    } else {
        if (n >= 10) {
            printnumber(n / 10); //second recursive call
        }
        putchar('0' + (n % 10));
    }
}
int main() {
    int n = 1234;
    printnumber(n);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW: `printnumber(INT_MIN)` is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

```one
First call to function, input 1234

   Second call to fucntion, input 123

      Third call to function, input 12

          Fourth call to function, input 1

          print 1 and return

      print 2 and return

   print 3 and return

print 4 and return

Output: 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the *function called first will print last*, i.e, the statement

```
putchar('0' + (n % 10));
```

will be executed for first time when `n` becomes less than `10` and this will print `1` then `2` then `3` and then `4`.

```
printnumber(1234) --> printnumber(123) --> printnumber(12) --> putchar('0' + (1 % 10))  
                                                                          |
                                                                          V 
  putchar('0' + (1234 % 10)) <-- putchar('0' + (123 % 10)) <-- putchar('0' + (12 % 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are printing after the recursive call.

So for your example it will be passing the following values (in order) to your `printnumber` function.

1. 1234
2. 123
3. 12
4. 1

Then, working its way back up, printing only the last digit of the passed in value.

To correct this, move your `putchar` line to before the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I see what your problem is, think of it like this.

- Call function;
- 1234 is greater than 10, so let's repeat the function.
- 123 is greater than 10, so let's repeat the function.
- 12 is greater than 10, so let's repeat the function.
- 1 is less than 10, and then do the if statement.

## now..

- We can print out 1 % 10;
- We can print out 12 % 10;
- We can print out 123 % 10;
- We can print out 1234 % 10;

The if statement isn't executed until the function is repeated until end.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is calling recursively before it prints the character, not after. Let's step through the code with your example of `1234`.

First, we call the function `printnumber(1234)`. In this function, we go immediately to the `else` block, which calls `printnumber(123)`, which in turn calls `printnumber(12)`, which calls `printnumber(1)`. Finally, `printnumber(1)` goes into the `else` block, but it is not `>= 10`, so it simply prints `1` and quits, returning to `printnumber(12)`, which now prints `2`, and so on.

Also, this is exactly what a debugger (such as gdb) is for.